# How to pass structure to callback function as an argument

Tags: c, callback

I am learning C and trying to pass structure to call back function. Gone through online resources but unable to pass structure to call back function. Here is my code.

```
// myvariables.h

struct callbackStruct
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
};
extern struct callbackStruct callbackStructObject;
typedef void (*callback)(struct callbackStruct);
extern void callback_reg(callback pointerRefCallback);

// Operations.c

struct callbackStruct callbackStructObject;

void callback_reg(callback pointerRefCallback) {

 (*pointerRefCallback)(callbackStructObject);

}

// main.c

struct callbackStruct myCallbackStruct1;
void my_callback(struct callbackStruct myCallbackStruct) {

 printf("A value:%d" + myCallbackStruct.a);

}

int  main()
{
 callback ptr_my_callback = my_callback(myCallbackStruct1);   
     callback_reg(ptr_my_callback);  
 return 0;
}
```

Can anyone resolve this scenario?

Comment: Can you describe the problem? (compiler/linker error, strange behavior...)

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article there  is a C example of passing a struct to a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 2):

The type `callback` is a function pointer type, e.g. a variable of that type is a pointer that points to a function that accepts a `struct callbackStruct` as single parameter:

```
typedef void (*callback)(struct callbackStruct);
```

So when you write (in main):

```
// ...
  callback ptr_my_callback = // HERE
// ...
```

The expression at `HERE` must be the address of a function with the correct signature. You write:

```
my_callback(myCallbackStruct1);
```

Since `my_callback` is a function that returns nothing (`void`) and the above expression **calls** this function, the expression

```
  callback ptr_my_callback = my_callback(yCallbackStruct1);
```

is not well formed (syntactically, as well as from the perspective of the type system).

Assuming that `my_callback` is the function that you want to work as a callback, you need to store its address in the pointer `ptr_my_callback`:

```
  callback ptr_my_callback = &my_callback;
```

It's kind of unclear what your code is supposed to achieve, though, so I cannot really help you any further.